# convert 2 columns dataframe to matrix by slicing rownames - R

Tags: r, unix, matrix

I have two data frames in R and I want to convert them to a matrix. Here is the example data I have

A data.frame `dat` with 2 columns, one column with names and second column with some scores.

```
> head(dat, n=20)
                                                     V1           V2
1                                      4star_Active_TSS  10.99561503
2                               4star_Bivalent_Enhancer   0.42425920
3                             4star_Bivalent_Poised_TSS   0.31163730
4                                       4star_Enhancers 139.64713405
5                             4star_Flanking_Active_TSS  23.11961717
6                       4star_Flanking_Bivalent_TSS_Enh   0.17654506
7                                 4star_Genic_enhancers  44.42394542
8                                 4star_Heterochromatin -34.61099049
9                                   4star_Quiescent_Low -28.54240987
10                             4star_Repressed_PolyComb  -0.42096698
11                           4star_Strong_transcription  12.70895605
12                        4star_Transcr_at_gene_5_and_3   0.00000000
13                        4star_Weak_Repressed_PolyComb   0.08902141
14                             4star_Weak_transcription  19.28859369
15                          4star_ZNF_genes_and_repeats  -1.58340662
16          A549_EtOH_0.02pct_Lung_Carcinoma_Active_TSS  14.01552989
17   A549_EtOH_0.02pct_Lung_Carcinoma_Bivalent_Enhancer   1.00466761
18 A549_EtOH_0.02pct_Lung_Carcinoma_Bivalent_Poised_TSS   1.20607773
19           A549_EtOH_0.02pct_Lung_Carcinoma_Enhancers  63.36004048
20 A549_EtOH_0.02pct_Lung_Carcinoma_Flanking_Active_TSS  48.27400816
```

Other data frame is with one column, contains the half name of `row.names` of above data frame.

```
> states=read.delim("states.txt", header=FALSE)
> states
                          V1
1                 Active_TSS
2          Bivalent_Enhancer
3        Bivalent_Poised_TSS
4                  Enhancers
5        Flanking_Active_TSS
6  Flanking_Bivalent_TSS_Enh
7            Genic_enhancers
8            Heterochromatin
9              Quiescent_Low
10        Repressed_PolyComb
11      Strong_transcription
12   Transcr_at_gene_5_and_3
13   Weak_Repressed_PolyComb
14        Weak_transcription
15     ZNF_genes_and_repeats
```

I want the resulting matrix/data.frame to be something like following. I want slice off the first data.frame's first column with second data.frame's column and create a matrix like the one below.

```
>dd_matrix
                                 Active_TSS Bivalent_Enhancer
4star                              10.99562         0.4242592
A549_EtOH_0.02pct_Lung_Carcinoma   14.01553         1.0046676
                                 Bivalent_Poised_TSS Enhancers
4star                                      0.3116373 139.64713
A549_EtOH_0.02pct_Lung_Carcinoma           1.2060777  63.36004
                                 Flanking_Active_TSS Flanking_Bivalent_TSS_Enh
4star                                       23.11962                 0.1765451
A549_EtOH_0.02pct_Lung_Carcinoma            48.27401                 1.1449923
                                 Genic_enhancers Heterochromatin Quiescent_Low
4star                                  44.423945      -34.610990     -28.54241
A549_EtOH_0.02pct_Lung_Carcinoma        5.976754       -1.274768     -31.68228
                                 Repressed_PolyComb Strong_transcription
4star                                     -0.420967            12.708956
A549_EtOH_0.02pct_Lung_Carcinoma          -0.331186             3.375022
                                 Transcr_at_gene_5_and_3
4star                                           0.000000
A549_EtOH_0.02pct_Lung_Carcinoma                1.501412
                                 Weak_Repressed_PolyComb Weak_transcription
4star                                         0.08902141           19.28859
A549_EtOH_0.02pct_Lung_Carcinoma             -0.05151471           11.19855
                                 ZNF_genes_and_repeats
4star                                        -1.583407
A549_EtOH_0.02pct_Lung_Carcinoma              0.000000
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Any `R` or `unix` solution would also work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `dplyr`/`tidyr`:

```
require(tidyverse);
df %>%
    separate(V1, into = c("what","states"), "_", extra = "merge") %>%
    spread(states, V2) %>%
    column_to_rownames("what");
#      Active_TSS Bivalent_Enhancer Bivalent_Poised_TSS Enhancers
#4star   10.99562         0.4242592           0.3116373  139.6471
#A549          NA                NA                  NA        NA
#      EtOH_0.02pct_Lung_Carcinoma_Active_TSS
#4star                                     NA
#A549                                14.01553
#      EtOH_0.02pct_Lung_Carcinoma_Bivalent_Enhancer
#4star                                            NA
#A549                                       1.004668
#      EtOH_0.02pct_Lung_Carcinoma_Bivalent_Poised_TSS
#4star                                              NA
#A549                                         1.206078
#      EtOH_0.02pct_Lung_Carcinoma_Enhancers
#4star                                    NA
#A549                               63.36004
#      EtOH_0.02pct_Lung_Carcinoma_Flanking_Active_TSS Flanking_Active_TSS
#4star                                              NA            23.11962
#A549                                         48.27401                  NA
#      Flanking_Bivalent_TSS_Enh Genic_enhancers Heterochromatin Quiescent_Low
#4star                 0.1765451        44.42395       -34.61099     -28.54241
#A549                         NA              NA              NA            NA
#      Repressed_PolyComb Strong_transcription Transcr_at_gene_5_and_3
#4star          -0.420967             12.70896                       0
#A549                  NA                   NA                      NA
#      Weak_Repressed_PolyComb Weak_transcription ZNF_genes_and_repeats
#4star              0.08902141           19.28859             -1.583407
#A549                       NA                 NA                    NA
```

Explanation: Separate `V1` into two columns by splitting on the first `"_"`; then `spread` into wide format by using `states` as key and `V2` as value, and turn column `what` into row names.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "                                                    V1           V2
1                                      4star_Active_TSS  10.99561503
2                               4star_Bivalent_Enhancer   0.42425920
3                             4star_Bivalent_Poised_TSS   0.31163730
4                                       4star_Enhancers 139.64713405
5                             4star_Flanking_Active_TSS  23.11961717
6                       4star_Flanking_Bivalent_TSS_Enh   0.17654506
7                                 4star_Genic_enhancers  44.42394542
8                                 4star_Heterochromatin -34.61099049
9                                   4star_Quiescent_Low -28.54240987
10                             4star_Repressed_PolyComb  -0.42096698
11                           4star_Strong_transcription  12.70895605
12                        4star_Transcr_at_gene_5_and_3   0.00000000
13                        4star_Weak_Repressed_PolyComb   0.08902141
14                             4star_Weak_transcription  19.28859369
15                          4star_ZNF_genes_and_repeats  -1.58340662
16          A549_EtOH_0.02pct_Lung_Carcinoma_Active_TSS  14.01552989
17   A549_EtOH_0.02pct_Lung_Carcinoma_Bivalent_Enhancer   1.00466761
18 A549_EtOH_0.02pct_Lung_Carcinoma_Bivalent_Poised_TSS   1.20607773
19           A549_EtOH_0.02pct_Lung_Carcinoma_Enhancers  63.36004048
20 A549_EtOH_0.02pct_Lung_Carcinoma_Flanking_Active_TSS  48.27400816", header = T)
```

Comment: Hi @Maurits, Thanks a lot. I modified the input `df` slightly. Is there a way to split `V1` based on last occurrence of `_` ? I checked `separate` function but I've little problem in understanding.

Comment: UPDATE: I wrote a shell script to keep only one `_`. Now it works perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @cat Just to clarify: In my solution `separate` splits terms on `"_"`, stores the first term in column `what` and stores the remaining *merged* terms in column `states`. This solution will work if `what` is always separated from `states` by the *first* underscore.

Comment: @cat PS. You can close the question and accept the solution that best answers your question by setting the tick mark next to a solution.

Comment: I have modified accordingly. Now I get the output according to my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The tricky thing seems to be that there is no separator between the state and the prefix and that some states are part of other states. Anyway, that is what I came up with:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat  %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(postfix = max(states$V1[str_detect(V1, states$V1)])) %>%
  mutate(prefix = str_replace(V1, str_c("_", postfix), "")) %>%
  melt(id.vars = c("postfix", "prefix"), measure.vars = "V2") %>%
  dcast(prefix ~ postfix)
```

In the first `mutate`, the longest matching state is identified to form the `postfix`. In the second `mutate` this `postfix` is removed to form the `prefix`.